# Serial port programming - Recognize end of received data

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I am writing a serial port application using VC++, in which I can open a port on a switch device, send some commands and display their output. I am running a thread which always read open port for output of given command. My main thread waits until read completes, but problem is how do I recognize that command output ends, and I should signal main thread.

Comment: This is a problem because of the variability of the output.  Unless there is a reason to wait, just show the received characters as they arrive or every x ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any serial port communication requires a *protocol*.  Some way for the receiver to discover that a response has been received in full.  A very simple one is using a unique byte or character that can never appear in the rest of the data.  A linefeed is standard, used by any modem for example.

This needs to get more elaborate when you need to transfer arbitrary binary data.  A common solution for that is to send the length of the response first.  The receiver can then count down the received bytes to know when it is complete.  This often needs to be embellished with a specific start byte value so that the receiver has some chance to re-synchronize with the transmitter.  And often includes a checksum or CRC so that the receiver can detect transmission errors.  Further embellishments then is to make errors recoverable with ACK/NAK responses from the receiver.  You'd be then well on your way in re-inventing TCP.  The RATP protocol in RFC-916 is a good example, albeit widely ignored.